# How to gather form data in a single cell of the database?

Tags: php

I have a php form which contains a `textbox` for NAME and a SUBMIT button. I want the form data to accumulate in a single cell of the database by every press of the SUBMIT button. The form data in that cell can be separated by commas.

My current code adds a new row on every submit, but I want all data to gather in a single row and single field i.e., in a single cell.

How to do this? I am very new to php and sql.

Comment: use  insert into for adding the values ???

Comment: A question like this would benefit greatly from a brief explanation for why you want to do this. What you describe would seem designed to undo the usefulness that one would experience from using a database. I ask because sometimes the questions asked here are not the root cause problem that someone is facing, but rather how to implement a workaround for their root cause problem.

Comment: You would need to use the [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function for that, *I do believe.*

Comment: Plus, I would advise "against" that, but that choice is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

- Query the database for the row data
- Get the Form data
- Append the data from the previous select with the new data
- Update the database field with the new data

Answer (score 0):

1. submit your values and on submit

   ```
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // your submit button
   ```
2. check values is not empty and escape string

   ```
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) { // your name input text
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   ```
3. Getting previous values of row

   ```
     $prev_res = mysql_query("select field_name from table");
     $result = mysql_fetch_row($prev_res);
   ```
4. update row with current+ previous row value

   ```
     $newvalue = $result->fieldname.','.$name; //adding comma
      $update = mysql_query("update table set fieldname='$newvalue' where fieldname=?");
   ```